# Prove that $Sym(p)$ is generated by any transposition and any p-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $Sym(p)$ is generated by any transposition and any p-cycle. Without loss of generality, we may assume the p-cycle to be $(1\space 2\space \dots\space p)$ just by 'relabelling' the entries with a bijection in any p-cycle. Again, without loss of generality, we actually want to prove that $Sym(p)=<(1\space k), (1\space 2\space \dots\space p)>$, where $k$ can take any value from $2$ to $p$, because even if the first entry of the transposition is not '$1$', say, it's '$2$', then since $(1\space 2\space \dots\space p)=(2\space 3\space \dots\space p\space 1)$, we can again 'relabel' the entries with a bijection.

Since we already know that $Sym(p)=<(1\space 2), (1\space 2\space \dots\space p)>$. Why do $(1\space k)$ and $(1\space 2\space \dots\space p)$ generate $(1\space 2)$ for arbitrary $k$?

Comment: If $g = (1,2,\ldots,p)$, then $g^{k-1}$ is a $p$-cycle starting with $(1,k,\ldots,)$, so replace $g$ by $g^{k-1}$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'replacing' $g$ by $g^{k-1}$?

Comment: I mean prove that ${\rm Sym}(p)$ is generated by $(1,k)$ and $g^{k-1}$. It then follows immediately that it is generated by $(1,k)$ and $g$.

Comment: I see... So I can make use of the fact that $p$ is a prime to conclude that $(1\space k\space \dots)$ is a p-cycle, and so with suitable 'relabelling', it generates $Sym(p)$ with $(1\space k)$ just like $(1\space 2\space \dots p)$ with $(1\space 2)$. Thanks very much!!!!

Comment: Yes exactly. Note that this argument doesn't work if $p$ is not prime. For example $(1,3)$ and $(1,2,3,4)$ do not generate $S_4$. In that example, my $g^k$ would become $(1,3)(2,4)$, which is not a $4$-cycle.